# Assigning random tuples to a dictionary

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary, random, tuples

Please I need help with this, Thank you.

```
for i in conflictList:
    d[i] = random.sample(set(domainList),2)
```

This assigns only a single tuple to the key
But i want to assign more than a single tuple, tried this but didnt work

```
for i in conflictList:
    while len(d[i]) < tup:
        d[i] = random.sample(set(domainList),2)
```

'tup' represents the number of tuples the user wants
do if the user wants 3 tuples, it gives something like this:
(x1,x2): (0,1), (1,2), (1,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in conflictList: 
    d[i] = []
    while len(d[i]) < tup:
        d[i].append(random.sample(set(domainList),2))
```

or

```
for i in conflictList:
    d[i] = [random.sample(set(domainList),2) for j in range(tup)]
```

Comment: thank you, the first one worked but the second one was giving an error of domainList not defined.

Comment: Of course you have to define it before this block. You just didn't in the second case.